# Make NA based on condition in Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I feel like this probably has a simple solution, I just can't figure it out.

I have a Pandas DF similar to this MWE:

```
In [92]: test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'B':[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]})

In [93]: test_df
Out[93]: 
   A  B
0  1  9
1  2  8
2  3  7
3  4  6
4  5  5
5  6  4
6  7  3
7  8  2
8  9  1
```

What I want is to set all values in that df that are less than 4 to be `np.nan`. I can get a df of booleans for this criteria:

```
In [94]: test_df < 4
Out[94]: 
       A      B
0   True  False
1   True  False
2   True  False
3  False  False
4  False  False
5  False  False
6  False   True
7  False   True
8  False   True
```

But I don't know the final step to make those True values `np.nan`. I thought this could be achieved with `test_df.loc` but I wasn't successful in my attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), by default `True` values of `boolean mask` are replaced by `NaN`:

```
print (test_df.mask(test_df < 4))
     A    B
0  NaN  9.0
1  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  7.0
3  4.0  6.0
4  5.0  5.0
5  6.0  4.0
6  7.0  NaN
7  8.0  NaN
8  9.0  NaN
```

Another solution is invert condition and simple assign:

```
test_df = test_df[test_df >= 4]
print (test_df)
     A    B
0  NaN  9.0
1  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  7.0
3  4.0  6.0
4  5.0  5.0
5  6.0  4.0
6  7.0  NaN
7  8.0  NaN
8  9.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You can assign `NaN` using [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
In [25]: test_df[test_df < 4] = np.nan

In [26]: test_df
Out[26]:
     A    B
0  NaN  9.0
1  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  7.0
3  4.0  6.0
4  5.0  5.0
5  6.0  4.0
6  7.0  NaN
7  8.0  NaN
8  9.0  NaN
```

alternative solution with "negated" condition:

```
In [43]: test_df.where(test_df >= 4)
Out[43]:
     A    B
0  NaN  9.0
1  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  7.0
3  4.0  6.0
4  5.0  5.0
5  6.0  4.0
6  7.0  NaN
7  8.0  NaN
8  9.0  NaN
```

or:

```
In [47]: test_df.where(~(test_df < 4))
Out[47]:
     A    B
0  NaN  9.0
1  NaN  8.0
2  NaN  7.0
3  4.0  6.0
4  5.0  5.0
5  6.0  4.0
6  7.0  NaN
7  8.0  NaN
8  9.0  NaN
```